# Borrar tres puntitos de video iframe mega.zn

Tags: iframe, html-video

como puedo eliminar los tres puntitos de este vídeo?

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" src="https://mega.nz/embed/bQFQgLpR#eLVDVA9ElQ0Cv8xKF4z3sc460Fb6ECurcftVZsXlo9M" allowfullscreen ></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es posible. Observando el código del reproductor embebido de MEGA, dicho elemento tiene la clase `.viewer-pending`, cuya búsqueda muestra operaciones de ocultar y mostrar con jQuery y que no están condicionadas por ningún parámetro de la URL como explica la respuesta anterior.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando se inserta un iframe, o algun elemento HTML del tipo embed, tengo entendido que lo que sucede es que se invoca un documento HTML dentro del documento propio, es decir, el tuyo.

En el caso de Youtube, mayormente la configuración de sus controles de video, estilos, etc. pasan por atributos en la sintaxis del HTML, o sinó también por parametros GET, los cuales se pasan por URL. (Que es lo que haces cuando especificas al atributo 'src').

En el caso de Youtube como dije, tiene una documentación en la cual te habla de los elementos del DOM que podes personalizar. Deberías buscar la documentación de Mega a ver si tiene una por el estilo. Pero indaga por ese lado... Parametros GET o atributos html para iframe